# How to initialize a jagged 2d array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a csv file that has things like, username, email, and a few other attributes some of the attributes are true false. However one attribute is another list of attributes. Which for some users are null. My thought for how I can use these is I can create a 2d arrray, where the first column is the user, and the following columns are the attributes. How can I initialize this array so when I use my foreach loop I can append to the row, for each attribute.

Comment: Please show some sample data and concrete example of working with it. I know we can help but without an example it would be a waste of the communitys time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize it as a hash instead of an array, and it works the way intended. $array1=@{}, then you can reference it and use $array[x]=(a,b,c,d,e) and so on.